# tsql group by months with dateadd()

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, dateadd, datepart

I'm grouping data with dateadd() by weeks, but I want to group by months instead. I've got this fun little dateadd function.

```
   DATEADD(day, - (1 * DATEPART(dw, Orders.OrderDate - 1)) + 1, CONVERT (date, Orders.OrderDate, 103))
```

so we're subtracting a week off of the current date - it seemed to me as simple as just changing the datepart to month and subtracting 1 from it,however, this gives me some pretty wacky results
 how do I modify this to subtract months instead of weeks?

Comment: those best thing I've come up with is DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Orders.OrderDate), 30) - but I'm not trusting the results I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

so you basically already tried:

DATEADD(day, - (1 * MONTH(dw, Orders.OrderDate - 1)) + 1, CONVERT (date, Orders.OrderDate, 103))

Comment: month only takes on parameter, month(date) as far as I can tell - so I did not try that yet